# Failed "symfony server:ca:install" : Access is denied

Tags: symfony, certificate, tls1.2, symfony5, windows-administration

when runing the command :

```
symfony server:ca:install
```

i have this error :

```
You might have to enter your root password to install the local Certificate Authority certificate

failed to install the local Certificate Authority: add cert: failed adding cert: Access is denied.
```

Notes :

- Symfony 5
- windows 10 64bits
- tested on cmd and powershell both runing as administrator

This command doesnt support a password param, so how can i go over this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
symfony serve
```

You can check this [link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads/server-setup) for more information.